# javascript jquery carrying html form POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO I have a form that look similar to

```
<form action="test.php" id="checksub"  method="post">
  <div>
    <select name="mydropdown">
      <option value="buy">buy</option>
      <option value="sell">sell</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  autocomplete text input that triggers "checksub"

  <input type="submit" id="checksub" name="checksub" style="visibility:hidden">
  <input type="submit" id="newsbutton" name="newsbutton">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#newbutton').click(function() {
    var newaction = "cantfinditems.php";
    $("#checksub").prop("action", newaction);
    $('#checksub').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Now the submit button is hidden because the autocomplete triggers it anyway,  but if the user cant find what they are looking for I want a button that says "cant find what your'e looking for?"
I want this button to have a different action to the form action, ie window.location = cantfinditems.php
but I also want to carry the POST data from the form ie  "mydropdown".
Thank you

Comment: when does the button gets displayed? on which event?

Comment: Why are you setting `.prop("newsbutton"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you need a second button, which calls a JavaScript function. In this function, you do a number of things:

Set the action attribute of the form to your alternate action (e.g. cantfinditems.php)

```
var newaction = "cantfinditems.php";
$("#form_id").prop("action", newaction);
```

Submit the form

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```

So a full example would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#yourbuttonid').click(function() {
  var newaction = "cantfinditems.php";
  $("#form_id").prop("action", newaction);
  $('#form_id').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you meant to change the `action` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct of course, I've edited my post accordingly.